# How columns are connected in posgresql and data autopopulate in between tables?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have to tables that I created through `models.py` in Django models and connect it to `postgresql` db. I have a common columns in two table `Departments`(`DepartmentName`) and `Employees` (`Department`) and say we want to add new row to `Employees` table.

The thing that confuses me since those two columns are `DepartmentName` and `Department` are same how can we make sure when the new recors are generated in `Employees` table how the records are auto populated in `Departments` table?

"models.py"

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Departments(models.Model):
    DepartmentId = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) # Autoincremented department id
    DepartmentName = models.CharField(max_length = 500)


class Employees(models.Model):
    EmployeeId = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) # Autoincremented department id
    EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    Department = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    DateofJoining = models.DateField()
    PhotoFileName = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

After inserting new records to Employees Table in postgresql table

```
insert into public"Employees" values (1, 'Bob', 'IT', '2021-12-12', 'anonyms.png')
```

[image]

Departments Table in when we inserted new records to

[image]

So my questions are
How can we connect those two tables when new records created in one of them the other gets populated with the data ? In this case `DepartmentName` data in `Departments` table.

Comment: you can read django documentation about relationships and how you can model your data  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#relationships

Answer (score 1):

1. Your models are not django neither python like models, so I'd rewrite them. Name of a model must be singular, dont use camelCase, dont duplicate name of model in name of fields.
2. To solve your problem, I'd redefine `save()` method in `Employee` model.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_of_joined = models.DateField()
    photo_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

   def save(self, **kwargs):
       Department.objects.get_or_create(name=self.department)
       super().save(**kwargs)
```

By the way, use `ForeignKey` in `Employee` model for `department` field.